# Project libraries which include jars (such as support v7 and play services) aren't working correctly

Tags: android

I switched over to Android Studio a few months ago, but only until recently did I ever add or remove library modules from my project. I've run into a problem where simply including the library module (such as google play services) is insufficient in getting my app to compile.

[image]

I made sure the library module uses its own jar as a dependency. The references jar can be seen here:

[image]

But unless I include both the library project AND this jar library onto my main app module as a dependency, the app will not compile. I was under the impression that just including the library itself ought to be enough, because it includes all the res/ files AND the jar itself which contains the java files.

I get it to work by doing the following:

[image]

But shouldn't just the 1 project library/module be enough? If you look you can see I need to do the same with Android v7's appcompat library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`You don't need to add the the compiled module (the .jar file) in the dependencies of itself module.`**

In other words, once you import your module to your project, the only other thing you should have to do is to add it as a module dependency to your project.

When you add the module library, Android Studio will automatically generate/add the `.jar` file to libraries and then to your project's dependencies.

**Module Dependencies**
[image: neither does Google Play Service Module]

---

**Google Play Services Library**
[image: Google play library has no dependencies]

---

**Main Project Module Dependencies**
[image: But Project depends on Google Play Services Module]

Comment: Yea, that's not working for me though. When I add the module library, regardless of whether or not the module library's jar is included as a dependency for itself, adding it and it alone to my project results in compile errors on the Java side. Attempting to import any classes from that module library will result in errors, unless the jar itself is a direct dependency of the main app module. Does that make sense?

Comment: Did you also include the Google Play Services as a module dependency?

Comment: Also make sure that module is marked as library module in _Facets_, but I think that is done automatically for you.

Comment: Yea, I did. see the 3rd screenshot in my question, the first instance of Google Play Services with the _lib suffix is the project module, the 2nd one is just the jar. What you're saying is what my previous experience was: the jar shouldn't be necessary, but for some reason it is for me.

Comment: Actually, if you look at my 3rd screenshot you will see that I have it there twice too. But I only added it once, I only added the module dependency, the *.jar dependency must have been added automatically.  
*The reason why you can't just add the jar is that you can't pack resources in JARs* AFAIK

Comment: Hmm. It seems like the jar isn't being automatically added for me. But when I do it manually like that it ends up working fine, and it's the right result even if the method for getting there is different. Thanks